# Smoothly / visually iterate words in Microsoft Word documents

Tags: c#, algorithm, vba, ms-word, interop

I have a loop on ActiveDocument.Characters.

I have retrieved a device context handle to the document area and want to display an overlay to smoothly highlight text from left-to-right, line by line.

The objective is to achieve smooth animation as if the application was guiding you to read at a certain speed.

The loop in itself is not, of course, smooth at all. Any suggestions for an algorithm.

Comment: What's not smooth about the loop?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Lol... The loop works fine... I am trying to animate a visual overlay as a reading guide. I will upload a C# sample that I wrote for reference soon.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: The code I have is all over the place. I will upload a C# sample shortly to illustrate the desired effect.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: Sounds good. BTW is it a VSTO Add-In or a simple C#-Word automation?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Eventually it will be an add-in. At the moment, I'm simply using a VBA Macro to experiment with. How can I upload the C# sample project here on SO by the way? It simulates what the resul should look like.

Comment: Just upload it anywhere you please and post the link here

Comment: @SiddharthRout: [Here](http://houseofsynergy.com/ReadingGuide.zip) is the link.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: [Here](http://houseofsynergy.com/ReadingGuide.zip) is the link.

Comment: +1 Good job done with the project ;)

Answer (score 1):

What's not so smooth about the animation? It is animating beautifully. Great job done :)

If you are referring to the way the next rectangle is drawn, I believe (*And I could be wrong*), It all depends on `this.RenderSpeed`. The smaller the value is, the more smoothly it will animate. In the current code, it will look it's best at `this.RenderGuidePoint.Offset(1, 0);` and worse at `this.RenderGuidePoint.Offset(25, 0);`.

I am not an expert on images but here is an example that I can think of (Not the best of examples though). Imagine a movie that you are watching, It all depends on the frame rate. If the fps is more than what a normal human eye can handle, you will notice that the image appears more abrupt (*Ex: When you fast forward a movie using 2X speed or a 4X*). Similarly the more .Offset() you go in your code, the more abrupt the drawing of the rectangle will look.

So what is the solution?

Since we cannot do much on the "X" of the next rectangle that is being drawn, we can manipulate the time interval of the Timer for a smoother creation (*Redrawing of the Rectangle*). **For testing purpose I hard-coded some values and was pleased with the output. See if you also get the results that I am getting.**

```
private void ToolStripComboBoxSpeed_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.RenderSpeed = (int) this.ToolStripComboBoxSpeed.SelectedItem;

    Switch (this.RenderSpeed)
    {
        case 5: TimerGuide.Interval = 50; break;
        case 10: TimerGuide.Interval = 40; break;
        case 15: TimerGuide.Interval = 30; break;
        case 20: TimerGuide.Interval = 20; break;
        case 25: TimerGuide.Interval = 10; break;
    }
}


private void PictureBox_Paint (object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
   //
   // '~~> Rest of the code remains same
   //

   //this.RenderGuidePoint.Offset(this.RenderSpeed, 0);
   this.RenderGuidePoint.Offset(1, 0);

   //
   // '~~> Rest of the code remains same
   //
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the effort. (1) The uploaded solution is very rough code as it was meant for a quick prototype. (2) The solution only indicates the desired effect. I actually want to import this text from Microsoft Word while preserving formatting which may vary from one character to the next affecting the character position and dimensions. (3) Next comment coming up.

Comment: (3) Your solution to speed up this app is more logical but will not work in a real world scenario because the timer component cannot guarantee a high resolution (FPS). Even if I were to use a more native Win32 timer, the WinForms refresh rate would most likely still limit smooth enough transitions. Double Bufffering could be a solution but I will need to look more into it.

Comment: Regarding your point 2: That is exactly what I mean when I was saying `Since we cannot do much on the "X" of...` Your code already calculates that based on the formatting of the character. Another way would be to change your dropdowns from `5-25` to say `1X-5X` and work in terms of speed... Just my 2 cents

Comment: Would you have any insight into getting the exact position and dimensions of each character? Of course I would have to use the RichTextBox control and draw on that instead of rendering to a picture box, which is what the uploaded solution does.